# Add logic inside of a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Note in the below query that the first two queries inside of the parenthesis, I've added two repeated queries, I'm sure that this is not a good practice. I need to repeat this query anytime where I need the value.

SQL Server is throwing an exception about not to write DECLARE inside of the SELECT keyword. What can I do or what I'm missing to refactor it?

```
SELECT A.StudentId,
(
    CASE WHEN (SELECT B.OverwrittenScore
        FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores AS B
        WHERE B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
        AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
        ) IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                SELECT B.OverwrittenScore
                FROM dbo.OverwrittenScores AS B
                WHERE B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
                AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId)
            ELSE (-- ANOTHER QUERY, BY THE MOMENT: SELECT 0 ) 
    END
) AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS A
```

Comment: I don't see a `DECLARE` in your query - hard to know what to fix when we can't see the problem.

Comment: what is the exact exception?

Comment: Well, as I'm executing two scalar queries, I was writting `DECLARE @value;  SET @value = SELECT...` instead of the CASE keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to look at using a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.StudentId,
    case 
        when B.OverwrittenScore is not null
        then B.OverwrittenScore
        else 0 
    end AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores B
    ON B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
    AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
```

If you want to use another select in the else, then you could add more joins as needed:

```
SELECT A.StudentId,
    case 
        when B.OverwrittenScore is not null
        then B.OverwrittenScore
        else c.whatever
    end AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores B
    ON B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
    AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
LEFT JOIN anothertable c
   ON a.col = c.col
```

Or even you could use `COALESCE` to replace the null values:

```
SELECT A.StudentId,
    coalesce(B.OverwrittenScore, 0) as FinalScore 
FROM dbo.Students AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores B
    ON B.StudentId = A.StudentId 
    AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
```

Comment: or simply `isnull(B.OverwrittenScore, 0)` instead of the `case` statement

Comment: @w0lf Yes, but they said there is another select in the else part, so a CASE might be better.

Comment: Or `coalesce()` because this is the SQL standard.

Comment: So you recommend to use several LEFT JOINS, I haven't see that point of view

Comment: @DarfZon the `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from `students` even if there is not a matching row in `OverwrittenScores`. If you want to return only matching rows, then use an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: COALESCE() is more universal but ISNULL is more efficient in T-SQL. Unless you feel there is a reasonable chance you are going to port to Oracle or there could be more than 2 options to compare I'd use ISNULL()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where error regarding `DECLARE` is coming from, but you could change what you *do* show to

```
SELECT 
    A.StudentId,
    COALESCE(B.OverwrittenScore, 0) AS FinalScore
FROM dbo.Students AS A
LEFT JOIN dbo.OverwrittenScores AS B
    ON A.StudentId = B.StudentId AND B.AssignmentId = @assignmentId
```